# Repeat sequence by group

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe:

```
a <-  data.frame(
  group1=factor(rep(c("a","b"),each=6,times=1)),
  time=rep(1:6,each=1,times=2),
  newcolumn = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,1,1,2,2,3,3)
)
```

I'm looking to replicate the output of `newcolumn` with a rep by group function (the `time` variable is there for ordering purposes). In other words, for each group, ordered by time, how can I assign a sequence `1,1,2,2,n,n`?  I also need a general solution (in the case that groups are of differing number of rows, or I want to repeat values `3,10,n` times).

For instance, I can generate that sequence with this: 
`newcolumn=rep(1:3,each=2,times=2)`

But that wouldn't work in a group by statement where `group1` has differing rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `data.table` alternative:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(a[1:2])

DT[order(time),newcolumn := rep(seq_len(.N/2), each=2, length.out=.N),by=c("group1")]
DT
#     group1 time newcolumn
#  1:      a    1         1
#  2:      a    2         1
#  3:      a    3         2
#  4:      a    4         2
#  5:      a    5         3
#  6:      a    6         3
#  7:      b    1         1
#  8:      b    2         1
#  9:      b    3         2
# 10:      b    4         2
# 11:      b    5         3
# 12:      b    6         3
```

Answer (score 4):

We specify the `length.out` in the `rep` after grouping by 'group1'

```
library(dplyr)
a %>% 
  group_by(group1) %>% 
  mutate(new = rep(seq_len(n()/2), each = 2, length.out = n()))
```

NOTE: `each` and `times` are not used in the same call.  Either we use `each` or `times`

EDIT: Based on comments from @r2evans

Comment: *"where `group1` has differing rows"* ... perhaps `rep(seq_len(n()/2),...)`?

Comment: @akrun you're too quick :)

Comment: The output gets a little messy with the division part for me, although the grouping seems to work.

Comment: @SlyGrogger  I think I placed the braces on the wrong place

Comment: Works perfect now!